# Android: Edit an image by 3rd party app / Intent ACTION_EDIT

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I'd like to use 3rd party apps like Skitch to "annotate" photos taken in my app and, of course, have the updated photo saved back to my app. The photos are stored in the private directories of my app and are exposed via a `ContentProvider`.

The Intent to open a 3rd party app looks like this:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setDataAndType("content://com.abc.xyz/fileName", "image/jpeg");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I'm expecting a result back in `onActivityResult()`, but I'm not getting an invocation there. I've also added log statements to the `update` and `insert` methods of my ContentProvider, but nothing's invoked there either.

The AndroidManifest.xml looks like this for the ContentProvider:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.abc.xyz" 
          android:enabled="true" 
          android:exported="true" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true"             
          android:name="com.abc.xyz.FileProvider"
          android:readPermission="true"
          android:writePermission="true" />
```

To complicate things, I'm doing that from a Cordova 3.9 application with a couple of "modified" plugins.

Can anyone point me to a working example (plain Android app) for such an integration and also confirm apps which support this kind of integration?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: The reason, why `onActivityResult()` never gets invoked may be, that the 3rd party application doesn't set a Result via `setResult()`.

Comment: What about a problem with nested Fragment or something like this ? Are you using fragments?

Comment: @SebastianWalla I tried a couple of differenent apps. Skitch, for example, doesn't even show the 'Save' option, only a 'Save As'. That's why I'm not sure if I'm just using the wrong apps or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @LaurentMeyer No, not using Fragments.

Comment: Ok because I had the issue with that. What I would try to do is test not with Skitch but with a normal camera app (passing a URI) and if it triggers the onActivityResult. If no, then, post your code in order that we really can help you. If yes, try without ContentProvider

Comment: Thanks @LaurentMeyer. Will give that a go. I tried earlier a version without ContentProvider and by copying the file into a publicly accessible directory, but had no success either.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting an invocation with the standard Android photo editor app.
Can anyone suggest any apps where annotations ARE working with ACTION_EDIT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard this one. Started from scratch again and it seems to be working.